# Setting a document ready timeout, how to set it up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully it will be a quick and easy question,

I am creating a simple function, but need to trigger it about 3-4 seconds after the page is loaded, just do not know how.

Here is my script

```
$(function () {
    var slideout = $('#slideout');
    slideout.animate({
        right: '-200px'
    }, 1000, function () {});
    $(".out").toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass('in');
        slideout.animate({
            right: '0px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
             duration: 500
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('in');
        slideout.animate({
            right: '-200px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 500
        });
    });
    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('out');
        slideout.animate({
            right: '-200px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 1000
        });
        slideout.fadeOut({
            duration: 1000
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Googling `javascript timeout` should get you on the right track!

Comment: `$(function(){ setTimeout(myfunc, 3000); /*other code */})` the passed function is invoked on document ready. you can add your timeout code there.

Comment: curious.. why 3-4 seconds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){

         //YOUR CODE

   },4000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, will accept you answer in few minutes

Comment: Why do we need to add settimeout inside document.ready? if document is ready then why settimeout is required?

Comment: @Simer Please read OP's Question carefully.. He said *I am creating a simple function, but need to trigger it about 3-4 seconds after the page is loaded,*'

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var doInteresting = function () {
        var slideout = $('#slideout');
        slideout.animate({
            right: '-200px'
        }, 1000, function () {});
        $(".out").toggle(function () {
            $(this).addClass('in');
            slideout.animate({
                right: '0px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            });
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('in');
            slideout.animate({
                right: '-200px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 500
            });
        });
        $(".close").click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('out');
            slideout.animate({
                right: '-200px'
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 1000
            });
            slideout.fadeOut({
                duration: 1000
            });
        });
    }

    setTimeout(doInteresting, 3000);
});
```